# dialogflow overriding the username

Tags: node.js, json, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I have a problem while creating a chatbot in dialog flow .

when I am typing

```
user : hi
Bot : What is your name? 
User : xyz
Bot : hi , xyz 
User : abc 
Bot : hi ,abc
```

It is overriding the name when I am setting the lifespan to more than 1, after that, I have to ask several questions and print the name in last with asked data.

and when I am setting the lifespan to more than 1, it does not allow me to print the name in next intent.

is there any solution?

Example conversation

[image: click here for screenshot]

List of Intents

[image: these are my intents]

Welcome Intent

[image: this my welcome intent]

GetName intent

[image: this myGetName intent]

Get Email intent

[image: this mygetemail intent]

Comment: Can you update your question to include screen shots of the Intents that you are trying to use and that you think should be matching inputs, along with any fulfillment code that you're using? It is very difficult to guide you when we don't know what you're doing. See [How do I Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have added included the screenshot , pls click on (click here for screenshot)

Comment: pls click on (click here for screenshot)

Comment: I did. It shows the conversation - not the Intent. We need to see the Intent or Intents that you're using.

Comment: i have added the screenshots in the query, pls check

Comment: Good so far. What does the "Get email" Intent look like.

Comment: and can you also show the input contexts?

Comment: i have added the getemail screenshot also with the input context

Comment: 1. (welcome intent) - output context : awaiting_name , 2. (get Name intent ) input context : awaiting_name and output context : awaiting_email , 3 (get email intent ) input context : awaiting_email and output context : awaiting_dob , 4 (get dob intent )   input context : awaiting_dob

Answer (score 0):

After you have accepted their name, and are prompting for the email, you have two contexts that are still valid:

- The `awaiting_name` context has a lifespan of 4 (since it was set in the welcome Intent, two intents ago)
- The `awaiting_email` context has a lifespan of 5 (since it was just set)

This means that two possible contexts could match:

- The `Get Name` context (because `awaiting_name` is valid)
- The `Get Email` context (because `awaiting_email` is valid)

Dialogflow is choosing the `Get Name` context, which is perfectly valid. Exactly which rules it applies to pick an Intent when there are multiple matches is complex, but any of them could be chosen.

As you surmise, you could set the lifespan to 1, which means you would accept only the next answer for the name or email. This would work, but is a bad idea, because it means they can't ask questions or ask for help. It is very non-conversational.

Better would be to clear out the context when you no longer need it. So your `Get Name` Intent can do this by setting the `awaiting_name` lifespan to 0 (and other Intents in similar ways). Something like this:

[image]

Comment: i did it but i am not able to print the name in get_email intent ..... i.e, ( XYZ,  We will contact you at akjsdhf@dhsf.com . What is your DOB? ) ... instead of that i am getting ( #awaiting_name.name We will contact you at akjsdhf@dhsf.com . What is your DOB? )